# Can't set up Listener in RecyclerView.Adapter, Casting issue

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-recyclerview

I've been trying to get this code running since the morning. I have a DialogFragment, which holds a Recycle View and it's the adapter. When I touch an item in the adapter it changes colour and sets that item with a flag. I want a listener to connect the touches to the Dialog so I'm able to pull the data. I have the below code...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using System.Linq;
using RecordMilk.ViewHolders;
using RecordMilk.Classes;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RecordMilk.Dialogs;

public class PregnantAnimalAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
public PregnantAnimalAdapter pregnantAnimalAdapter;
public List<Animal> mAnimals;
public Herd passedHerd;
public OnFinishClick callback;
public OnItemClick itemCallback;
string[] animalTags;
//public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;

public interface OnFinishClick
{
    void OnFinishClick(List<Animal> animals);
}

public interface OnItemClick
{
    void OnItemClick(List<Animal> animals);
}

public PregnantAnimalAdapter(string SerializedString)
{
    passedHerd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Herd>(SerializedString);

    List<Animal> animals = passedHerd.Animals.ToList();
    animalTags = animals.Select(x => x.FreezeBrand).ToArray();

    var size = from x in animalTags
               orderby x.Length, x
               select x;

    animalTags = size.ToArray();

    mAnimals = animals;
}



public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).
                                  Inflate(global::RecordMilk.Resource.Layout.PregnancyItem, parent, false);

    try
    {
        // Getting Casting Error here...
        itemCallback = (OnItemClick)parent.Context;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }

    PregnantAnimalViewHolder vh = new PregnantAnimalViewHolder(itemView);

    vh.mBackground.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    {
        Animal pregAnimal = mAnimals.Find(x => x.FreezeBrand == animalTags[vh.AdapterPosition]);

        pregAnimal.Pregnant = !pregAnimal.Pregnant;

        if (pregAnimal.Pregnant)
        {
            vh.mBackground.SetBackgroundResource(RecordMilk.Resource.Color.munster_yellow);
        }
        else
        {
            vh.mBackground.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color.White);
        }
        NotifyDataSetChanged();

        itemCallback.OnItemClick(mAnimals);
    };

    return vh;
}

public override void OnAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)
{
    base.OnAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

}

public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{

    PregnantAnimalViewHolder vh = holder as PregnantAnimalViewHolder;

    vh.mAnimalTag.Text = animalTags[position];

    if (mAnimals.Find(x => x.FreezeBrand == animalTags[position]).Pregnant == true)
    {
        vh.mBackground.SetBackgroundResource(RecordMilk.Resource.Color.munster_yellow);
    }
    else
    {
        vh.mBackground.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color.White);
    }
}

public override int ItemCount
{
    get { return mAnimals.Count; }
}
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
>     at PregnantAnimalAdapter.OnCreateViewHolder (Android.Views.ViewGroup parent, System.Int32 viewType)

I had this code in an Activity previously and worked as expected. But I needed to put the functionality into a DialogFragment which is where the issue started showing itself.

Comment: Can't you just check what type it is using `QuickWatch`?

Comment: Hi G.hakim, I'm trying to get the listener up and running correctly. Maybe the question is misguiding about the cast. It says it's an unknown Identifier. I previously had this code working in a activity and worked fine. I needed to move it to a DialogFragment.

Comment: parent.Context isn't always the correct 'nearest neighbour' I would pass through the Fragments Context to the Adapters Constructor and store it in a variable to use.

Comment: Haven't even thought about that! Keep forgetting we can pass the context of our fragments etc. I'll have a look into that, thanks for giving this information!

Comment: Did you solve this issue? If yes, Can you share a solution to answer?